# BigQuery Firewall Domains

Tags: java, google-bigquery, firewall

I am running a java application from behind our corporate firewall to access our Google BigQuery data. The application is very similar to the [getting started sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigquery-samples-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigquery/samples/BigQueryJavaGettingStarted.java) and uses many of the same Google APIs. We have added an exception rule for the google.com domain (including accounts.google.com, accounts.l.google.com, bigquery.cloud.google.com, and www3.l.google.com) to allow traffic to these sites through our firewall.

The application works, except when the Google APIs route some of the traffic through the 1e100.net domain. This appears to be a domain owned by Google. Rather than continuing to add domains to our firewall rules based on trial and error, I was hoping to find a list of domains that the Google BigQuery APIs use so we can add them all.

Is there a list of domains used by the Google BigQuery APIs that we can add to our firewall rule?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/174717?hl=en), starting in october 2009, Google regrouped all its service under that domain, so simply adding "1e100.net" should be enough.